# Make synchronous AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make synchronous AJAX requests So i have used async as false. But it is working for me. `$anchorScroll`
Am I placing async in correct place?

```
$.post("/jquery_post.php", {async: true}, params,
function(response) {
    /* ToDO with Response */
});
```

Please correct me where am i wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) as [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) don't accept any config object

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'post',
    data: params,
    async: false
}).done(function (response) {
    /* ToDO with Response */
})
```